# to store the value of checkbox in data base

Tags: .net

I make a aproject of attendance management in which i need to select multipal check box and store the value of that checkbox to the database . plez tell me the source code of this ?

Comment: So, how is your project going so far? Can you show us the progress you've made, the research you did to tackle the problem? Any difficulties you might have encountered? Did you read [this post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)? If you haven't I would recommend you doing so before asking you next question on StackOverflow as this one is definitely not going well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an advice for this:

1. Create a boolean column in the database.
2. Convert the checkbox value to boolean true or false and then save this value in this column.